# Get the first link in Div contenteditable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to get the first link (text type) in div contenteditable. in my Div, my value is:

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true" value="http://google.com and other string but i only get the link"></div>
```

i want to get only http://google.com

And the second problem, when value is `http://google.com http://yahoo.com` i want to get only the first link `http://google.com`.

I use jquery with keyup event in div contenteditable. Hope you can help me, thank you!

Updating my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#content").keyup(function(){
    var link = $("content").text();
    console.log(link);
  });
}
```

and html

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make a demo in Jsfiddle it will describe it more.

Comment: Obviously you have some code, please show the relevant part of it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i'll updating my question

Comment: Which is `#txtContent` div?

Comment: it is `content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content").keyup(function(){
    var link = $("#content").text().match(/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})/i)[1];
    
    alert(link);
  });
});
```

I have made some correction and added regex to match url.

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7k24kmg9/1/)